# In PyCharm, is there a way to have the Markdown preview beneath the code?

Tags: pycharm

I am using a single laptop screen to work, and I have my PyCharm open on the right half of the screen. In that window I have open both the Markdown code(?) as well as the preview. Right now they're to the left and right of each other, but I'd prefer if the preview was beneath the code.  Is there any way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried right-click on the tab and split horisontaly?

Comment: There is no such option if I right-click on the body of the markdown itself. If I right-click on the tab I see the usual "Split Horizontally" option, but that moves both the Markdown "code" as well as its preview while keeping their relative orientation the same (i.e. left-and-right).